# Giving Authorization or Permission to Apps Script goes wrong

Tags: google-apps-script, google-account

I wrote a telegrambot using Google Apps Script.

And I coded like this:

```js
function setWebhook() {
  const resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(botUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + hookUrl);
  Logger.log("SetWebhook response:", resp.getResponseCode());
}

function getWebhook() {
  const resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(botUrl + "/getWebhookInfo");
  if (resp.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    const data = JSON.parse(resp.getContentText());
    Logger.log("Current webhook is", data.result);
  } else {
    Logger.log("GetWebhook response:", resp.getResponseCode());
  }
}
```

After I select the function *getWebhook* and click *RUN*, a pop-up window says "this app isn't verified".

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yKIg.png)

Then I click *Advanced* and click *Go to TGBot (Unsafe)*, but the verification is still unsuccessful, and a toast says "Something went wrong, try again".

What I have tried:

- switch my browser from Chrome to Edge
- Use different Google accounts, and start a new project
- Erase my browser data

But nothing is working.

Comment: You may try to create a issue in the issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [issue post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374#comment322)
and documentation: [Fix issues with multiple Google Accounts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects#fix_issues_with_multiple_google_accounts)

> Fix issues with multiple Google Accounts
>
> If you're logged into multiple Google Accounts at the same time, you
> might have trouble accessing your Apps Script projects, add-ons, and
> web apps. Multi-login, or being logged into multiple Google Accounts
> at once, isn't supported for Apps Script, add-ons, or web apps.
>
> To fix issues from multi-login, try one of the following solutions:
>
> - Log out of all your Google Accounts and only log in to the one that has the Apps Script project, add-on, or web app you need to access.
> - **Open an incognito window in Google Chrome, or an equivalent private browsing window, and log in to the Google Account that has the
>   Apps Script project, add-on, or web app you need to access.**

In my case which was similar it helped.